# How to use two conditions on string search using gsub in R?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a vector of characters and I want to search for everytime "RR" appears, and replace by "" empty space. But I can´t miss the "ANRR". I was wondering something like:

```
gsub("RR|!ANRR", "",charvector$vector)
```

But it doesn´t work. I was wondering how to include "OR" and "NOT" in the same expression?

Comment: Not clear about the `|`  here. Can you show a small example with expected output

Comment: I was trying to use | as a "OR" operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps we need to have a word boundary  (`\\b`) or a space (`\\s`) to make sure that it would only match the 'RR' and not 'ANRR'

```
gsub("\\bRR\\b", "",charvector$vector)
```

Or if we want to replace 'RR' on a substring of a word which doesn't precede with 'AN'

```
gsub("(?<!AN)RR", "", charvector$vector, perl = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
charvector <- data.frame(vector = c('hello RR sds ANRR dss RR', 
         'RR dds ANRR CNRR'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I tryied this, but what if only the pattern "ANRR" should be preserved? All the other cases where "RR" appears, we need to remove.

Comment: @Bindini Can you try my update

Comment: It was solved by your solution on the update.